# What's the difference between Subtract and op_Subtraction for XNA Vectors?

Tags: vector, xna

In the help for XNA Vector3, two of the public methods that it lists are Subtract and op_Subtraction.  What's the difference between them and when should one be used instead of the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`op_Subtraction` (the `-` operator implementation) and `Vector3.Subtract` are essentially the same thing. They create a new vector with values from a subtraction operation. `Vector3` is a value type, so there is no memory-management cost, however there is a small construction cost.

The other overload of Subtract is slightly different:

```
void Vector3.Subtract(ref Vector3 value1, ref Vector3 value2, out Vector3 result)
```

This one takes references for its input and for its output. It is better for data-oriented programming (for example: a tight loop in, say, a physics engine, which takes data from one array and outputs it into another array). This removes the construction cost, and the cost of passing 6 floats as arguments, however there is still a tiny cost for the function call and dereferencing.

You can get even faster by doing the subtraction directly:

```
result.X = value1.X - value2.X;
result.Y = value1.Y - value2.Y;
result.Z = value1.Z - value2.Z;
```

Of course, as you select faster options, you also lose readability! This is much clearer:

```
result = value1 - value2;
```

So to answer your question - you should absolutly use the vector `-` operator when doing vector subtraction, *unless* you're writing some kind of very high-performance data-oriented thing ***and*** you have profiled your code and found it to be a worthwhile performance improvement.

If you're interested in more low-level performance information like this, take a look at [Understanding XNA Framework Performance](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=B11AD912-4158-44CC-A771-A5E044F7E3BB&displaylang=en) by Shawn Hargreaves. (In fact it includes a benchmark comparing the three methods I have listed here, when used in a particle system.)

Comment: I am very much interested in performance, so I really appreciate knowing how to do subtraction faster, and the book reference.

Answer (score 1):

`op_Subtraction()` is the implementation for the `-` operator but otherwise they are the same:

```
vectorA - vectorB
Vector3.Subtract(vectorA, vectorB)
```